# how to fill my empty last row using for loops VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hello i tried to make a data table that consist a range of raw material with list of vendors like this image
[image]
the data source is in another sheet
[image]
the idea is to collect every unique content in supplier sheet and extract it to data table sheet (Row 1) so every raw material Category have a column that consist list of suppliers. but the problem i can't make the supplier name fill in every empty last row in each column and i can't have more than one supplier for each column. is there anyone can tell me what have i done wrong in my code?

this is my code

```
Sub uniquevalues()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim arrS As New Collection, b
Dim rngRawCategory As Variant
Dim rngSupplier As Variant
Dim lrow As Long

rngSupplier = Range("C4:C1000") 'range in supplier sheet (Sheet3)
rngRawCategory = Range("D4:D1000") 'range in supplier sheet (Sheet3)


On Error Resume Next
For Each a In rngRawCategory
    arr.Add a, a
Next

On Error Resume Next
For Each b In rngSupplier
    arrS.Add b, b
Next

Sheet12.Range("B1:Z1000").ClearContents

For i = 1 To arr.Count
    Sheet12.Cells(1, i + 1) = arr(i)
    For X = 1 To arrS.Count
        If Sheet3.Cells(X + 3, 4).Value = arr(i) Then
            lrow = Sheet12.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheet12.Cells(lrow, i + 1) = arrS(X)
        End If
    Next
Next


Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses a dictionary to extract the unique row materials name and the corresponding supplier for each:

```
Sub SuppliersPerUniqueMat()
 Dim shMast As Worksheet, shSuppl As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrMast, arrFin
 Dim dict As Object, arrS, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, maxCol As Long
 
 Set shMast = Sheet3 ' sheet code Name!
 Set shSuppl = Sheet12
 lastR = shMast.Range("C" & shMast.rows.count).End(xlUp).row   'last row in the master sheet
 arrMast = shMast.Range("C2:D" & lastR).value                  'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")               'create the necessary dictionary object
 
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrMast)                                ' iterate between the array elements
       dict(arrMast(i, 2)) = dict(arrMast(i, 2)) & "|" & arrMast(i, 1) 'place unique keys (materials) and their suppliers
       If maxCol < UBound(Split(dict(arrMast(i, 2)), "|")) Then
            maxCol = UBound(Split(dict(arrMast(i, 2)), "|"))           'determine the maximum suppliers number
       End If
  Next i
  'redim the filan array to take maximum occurrences rows and dict number of items:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To maxCol + 1, 1 To dict.count): k = 1
  
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1  'iterate between the dictionary keys/items:
        arrFin(k, i + 1) = dict.Keys()(i): k = k + 1 'place the dictionary key in the first row
        arrS = Split(dict.items()(i), "|")           'split the item to extract suppliers in an array (0 is empty)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrS)                    'iterate between the array elements
            arrFin(k, i + 1) = arrS(j): k = k + 1    'place the suppliers of a specific key
        Next j
        k = 1                                        'reinitialize k for the next material
  Next i
  'drop the final array content at once:
  shSuppl.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: @muntun Did you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: yes! thank you very much it works perfectly sorry for my late respond